# pip error on installing packages on command prompt

Tags: python, pip, pygame

Hi I have installed Anaconda/jupyter notebook but there is an error

[image]

and this is the text which appeared

```
C:\Users\DELL>pip install pygame
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pygame/ 
    (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ 
    (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: Hi I am using Anaconda/jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi every one the Answer is that instead of using CMD I used Anaconda Powershell prompt and it worked great. No SSl error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
pip install pygame==1.9.6release --allow-external pygame --allow-unverified pygame.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the python you use is not compiled with ssl support (`because SSL module is not available`).

As pypi.org use SSL, you won't be able to install packages from there.

Comment: So What should I do

Comment: install a python with ssl support !

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem as you. I tried a lot of thing's, and just one worked.
The problem may be caused by DLL archives in *Windows\System32* folder (such as libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll , libssl-1_1-x64.dll or other's).

The solution was installing openSSL from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html that replaces DLL'S to upgraded versions.

Hope it work's!